# Delete extension from Magento Connect

Tags: php, magento

I want to delete two of my extensions from Magento Connect as these have not been approved by Magento team. I cannot find any way to do this.
Can anyone tell me how to delete my unapproved extensions from Magento Connect?

Comment: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/11900/   ...view this page...it might help you

Comment: I'm also looking for a way to do this. I'm not finding anything. And the Magento Support team isn't responding to any emails about it.